# Authenticating against Bronto REST Api using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, bronto

I've set hallmonitor (OAuth 2.0 compliant service) in a Bronto sandbox, but using RestSharp I can't get the access token to be able to make further calls to the REST API.

I've been able to successfully use curl i.e.

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET" https://auth.bronto.com/oauth2/token
```

I've tried a number of variations of the code below, but nothing seems to work, I always get an error response.

```
{
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed (e.g., unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method).",
    "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

Simplified sample code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://auth.bronto.com");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientId, secret);
//client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator(CLIENT_ID, clientId, CLIENT_SECRET, secret);

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/oauth2/token", Method.POST);
//request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + client);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
//request.AddParameter(CLIENT_ID, clientId);
//request.AddParameter(CLIENT_SECRET, secret);

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Has anyone used RestSharp with Bronto REST API to successfully authenticate and get the access token?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137735/9533368

Comment: Have already looked over that question and the accepted solution, nothing specified seems to work.